# SpringData and MongoDB configuration error : MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, persistence, mongotemplate

I am currently attempting an integration of mongodb to my spring application.

I have the initial mongodb environment setup on my machine, service startup, etc.

However on the application configuration in spring there is an error related to the mongoTemplate construction-arg

> "wildcard is strict but no declaration found for element"

I've actually used the same xml outlay as described in the documents [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-xml-config), the same as some recent tutorials online, and as far as I can tell I have addded the correct namespace urls. So i am a bit lost at the moment as to what I am missing. Any help on this is most appreciated.

Here is a look at the xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />




    <!-- scanning comment root context of all components package directory-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />


    <!--Dispatcher servlet-->
    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- mongo db config -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"  id="mongo" />

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.demo.football.repository" />

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="FootballManager"/>
    </beans:bean>



</beans:beans>
```

Comment: what version of spring-data and spring-data-mongodb are you using ?

Comment: spring-mongo-mongodb is version 1.7.2, there is no spring-data dependency required - as far as I am aware ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the xsd names to match the spring version you're using.

Considering you're using Spring 4, the xshema name space will change to following.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.7.xsd">
```

Comment: This has done the trick. Any explanation as to why this is the case or spring is being picky?Thank you Veeram!

Comment: Yes, the name attribute for consturctor-arg is only available after spring 3. So when you don't qualify the xsds the spring resolves it to earlier version when the name attribute was not available.

Comment: very nice. i am new to spring in the grand scheme of things. thank you.